# ASP.NET Session - Internal ArrayList exception

Tags: asp.net, session, arraylist, memory-management, windbg

We have a web based application developed using the .NET framework 4 and ASP.NET MVC.When you set an item to a session in a section of the code, we are faced with an internal exception directly from **mscorlib** which causes our application to work unexpectedly.The fault stack trace is as follows;

```
0:072> !clrstack
OS Thread Id: 0x31ec (72)
        Child SP               IP Call Site
000000aea766d968 000007f9736a4650 [HelperMethodFrame: 000000aea766d968] 
000000aea766da50 000007f9674e0e5a System.Collections.ArrayList.Add(System.Object)
000000aea766da90 000007f966655292 System.Collections.Specialized.NameObjectCollectionBase.BaseAdd(System.String, System.Object)
000000aea766dae0 000007f9650ac4c9 System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateItemCollection.set_Item(System.String, System.Object)
000000aea766db20 000007f90ed89ce9 UTL.WebStateManager.set_Item(System.String, System.Object)
000000aea766dbf0 000007f90f29370c WebStateManagerHelper.get_OriginalPNR()
000000aea766dc80 000007f90f29242d QueryDynamicLoggingComponent.LogTransaction(System.String, System.String)
000000aea766e110 000007f90f2917e3 WSHelper.Log(System.String, System.String, Boolean, System.String)
000000aea766e160 000007f90f28fd17 WSHelper.GetResponse(System.String, SecurityInfo, System.String, System.String, System.String ByRef, System.String, System.String)
000000aea766e5d0 000007f90f29eae6 WSHelper.SendQuery(System.String, SecurityInfo, System.String)
000000aea766e7f0 000007f90f29e7f8 WSHelper.SendQuery(SecurityInfo, System.String)
000000aea766e840 000007f90f29e4af APIWSPool.SendAndReceiveQueryToString(Agency, System.String, Token, Boolean)
000000aea766e940 000007f90f29e374 APIWSPool.SendAndReceiveQuery(Agency, Token, Boolean)
000000aea766e9b0 000007f90f6168f4 FlightBookingManager.SearchFlightForMPSearchedFlightRecommendations1(Agency, FlightFareDrivenSearchInfo, Boolean)
000000aea766eb80 000007f90f615ec1 ApiFlightBookingProvider.SearchFlightForMPSearchedFlightRecommendations1(Agency, FlightFareDrivenSearchInfo, Boolean)
000000aea766ebe0 000007f90f6158f2 APICOM.Threading.OWCOutboundSearchThread.Work()
000000aea766edb0 000007f9674e2d45 System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
000000aea766ef10 000007f9674e2ab9 System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
000000aea766ef40 000007f9674e2a97 System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
000000aea766ef90 000007f9674fa161 System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
000000aea766f2a8 000007f96e0eab53 [GCFrame: 000000aea766f2a8] 
000000aea766f5f8 000007f96e0eab53 [DebuggerU2MCatchHandlerFrame: 000000aea766f5f8] 
000000aea766f788 000007f96e0eab53 [ContextTransitionFrame: 000000aea766f788] 
000000aea766f9a8 000007f96e0eab53 [DebuggerU2MCatchHandlerFrame: 000000aea766f9a8]
```

When I run **!dso** in the thread I am receiving the error and look at the ArrayList that the Session uses, I can't see any problem.

```
0:072> !DumpObj /d 000000adb1348540
Name:        System.Collections.ArrayList
MethodTable: 000007f967727868
EEClass:     000007f967109b60
Size:        40(0x28) bytes
File:        C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll
Fields:
              MT    Field   Offset                 Type VT     Attr            Value Name
000007f9676b31c0  4000c2f        8      System.Object[]  0 instance 000000abf0b6ec10 _items
000007f967722238  4000c30       18         System.Int32  1 instance               17 _size
000007f967722238  4000c31       1c         System.Int32  1 instance               17 _version
000007f96771fca0  4000c32       10        System.Object  0 instance 0000000000000000 _syncRoot
000007f9676b31c0  4000c33      5e8      System.Object[]  0   shared           static emptyArray
                                 >> Domain:Value  000000ab6a93ba10:000000ac6b0b23c0 000000aea416c820:000000ac2b1f8730 <<
0:072> !DumpObj /d 000000abf0b6ec10
Name:        System.Object[]
MethodTable: 000007f9676b31c0
EEClass:     000007f9671078f8
Size:        288(0x120) bytes
Array:       Rank 1, Number of elements 32, Type CLASS (Print Array)
Fields:
None
0:072> !DumpArray /d 000000abf0b6ec10
Name:        System.Object[]
MethodTable: 000007f9676b31c0
EEClass:     000007f9671078f8
Size:        288(0x120) bytes
Array:       Rank 1, Number of elements 32, Type CLASS
Element Methodtable: 000007f96771fca0
[0] 000000adb1348b90
[1] 000000adb1348c08
[2] 000000adb137e268
[3] 000000adb137e348
[4] 000000adb137e5c8
[5] 000000adb137e6b0
[6] 000000adb137e8d0
[7] 000000adb137ea98
[8] 000000adb137eb48
[9] 000000adb13f57d8
[10] 000000adb13f5a78
[11] 000000adb13f5b08
[12] 000000adb13f9018
[13] 000000adb13f9470
[14] 000000adb14b7618
[15] 000000abf0b6e4d8
[16] 000000abf0b6ebf0
[17] null
[18] null
[19] null
[20] null
[21] null
[22] null
[23] null
[24] null
[25] null
[26] null
[27] null
[28] null
[29] null
[30] null
[31] null
```

We know that the Session is not thread-safe for some operations.When we analyzed dumps we didn't see any other thread trying to access the same session object.We checked the source code of .NET in **referencesource.microsoft.com** and we think that it is a related an error indexing the internal array of the ArrayList.I'm not sure, but it seems to have a memory problem.Any ideas?

Comment: SessionStateItemCollection is thread safe but the items aren't. Could it be related to the items?

Comment: Putting complex objects as items? What is the session mode (I.e. Serialization issue if not in-proc)?

Comment: I use session as In-Proc mode and yes it contains lot of complex objects.

Comment: By the way session isn't thread safe.I have not seen any sync (lock, concurrent list etc) code in the source code.

Comment: If it a lot of stuff what happens when a session end event is fired? Do you grab it in global? Could it be a memory issue?

Comment: @MatthewCampbell In fact, there is nothing we do when the session ends.I am sure there is a memory problem. But I can not find exactly what the cause is.
This is exactly the point of the error; (IndexOutOfRangeException)

        `public virtual int Add(Object value) {
            Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<int>() >= 0);
            if (_size == _items.Length) EnsureCapacity(_size + 1);
            _items[_size] = value;
            _version++;
            return _size++;
        }`

The state of the ArrayList is already above.

Comment: SessionStateBehavior isn't disabled on the controller otherwise write session calls should be serialized (thus why there are no locks when grabbing items)? How often does the fault occur?

Comment: @MatthewCampbell We encounter this error very often.I did not understand what you said.Could you give me some more detail?

Comment: See http://tech-journals.com/jonow/2011/10/22/the-downsides-of-asp-net-session-state

Comment: I understand what you mean.We do not use the session this way.if I had a aync request, I would see it in the dump file.This is a booking process. The request is going through a single thread.I'm sure there is no concurrency problem :( Please also look at the stack trace and Array List memory state in dump.It's very strange to get an index error.

Comment: Can you'll switch over to an out proc solution to see if serialization and avoiding recycling could fix the problem until the bug can be reproduced in test.